# "undefined function call" when using function in a DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a `DataSet` in `UserAdmin.xsd` with many `DataTable`s. Most of the data come directly from stored procedures. However for one of the tables, I would like to add another column which uses a C# function defined in another file.

I put for the expression for that column: `Helper.ObtainUserInfo(user_nm, "displayname");` but that gives me an error "undefined function call".

`Helper.cs` is located under `App_Code/Common/` and the namespace is `COM.A.B.C`. `UserAdmin.xsd` is located under `App_Code/`.

How can I access the function `ObtainUserInfo()`? Is there something like a `using` keyword that I could use?

Comment: Please provide more context for the code in question.

Comment: `UserAdmin.xsd` is just an XML file describing a `DataSet` so there really isn't any "code". I don't have this problem anymore but I'll leave this open to answers if anyone comes up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `DataColumn.Expression` to call a .NET-Method to obtain a value. You must refer a column in this table or one of the parent/child tables to calculate the value. For more informations on what you can('t) do with `Expressions` look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Instead of using a method or an expression, i would recommend to do this with SQL whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

if You provide your code, then it would be very helpful to solve your problem, anyway assuming your problem i have solution, i hope it may helped you

You can open the Code File Which Contain ObtainUserInfo() Function, then You can Refer that Class Name, in other File. 
For eg : If you hav solution Named WebApplication1, inside that if you have users class, in that users class, ObtainUserinfo() function is defined, 
then You Have to Use  statement like this,

`Using WebApplication1.Users`